# Saving time in Postgres with or without TZ?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a column in the DB that supposed to represent a deadline for ordering.
Let's assume the value is 11am EST.
I've saved in the DB as UTC during Winter so it was saved as 4PM UTC.
Problem is, when DST starts, the conversion back to EST was 12PM...
How can I solve this? on the DB level? if so how would I save a constant time and convert it to the correct value? If I use timestamp with TZ, will it then be read as 5PM UTC?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are referring to? Is the the data being stored to a `time with time zone` field? If so don't, that is a useless data type. If you are storing to a timestamp then use `timestamptz`. `timestamptz` will store values as `UTC`. What you see on retrieval will depend on the server `TimeZone` setting. It is spelled out here [Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps*.

Comment: "[The] Problem is, when DST starts, the conversion back to EST was 12PM..." -- PostgreSQL handles time zones correctly and this shouldn't be an issue, unless the server is incorrectly managed. Please elaborate on how to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you described is caused by converting a future time to UTC and back again, using two different UTC offsets (UTC-5 and UTC-4).  In general, one should not store future times (whether recurring or single-instance) in terms of UTC, unless the original reference point is *already* in terms of UTC. The advice "Always use UTC" applies only for past/present timestamps.  It does not apply for future values.

PostgreSQL has several different [date/time data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).  The "with time zone" types will convert to/from UTC implicitly.  The "without time zone" types will not.

In your case, it sounds like you would like to have a time-only value that describes the deadline that applies *every* day.  Thus, you should use a `time` (aka `time without time zone`) data type for that field.  You should then also store the [IANA time zone ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in a separate character field (`varchar(50)` should be sufficient).  For US Eastern Time, you would store `'America/New_York'`.  That assumes the cutoff is based on the same time zone for all users.  If rather you are cutting it off at *their* time zone, then it could be different per-user, and you will need to determine the user's time zone.

When evaluating whether the deadline has passed, you would take the current UTC timestamp and convert it to the local date and time in the target time zone to have the current date and time in that zone.  You'd then take a copy of that and replace the time part with your deadline time. Then compare those two values to see if the deadline has passed.

You should also be thinking about when does the deadline reset for the next day.  Is it strictly based on the local date?  If they try to order past that deadline, do you disallow it (and if so when do you allow it again), or does it apply to the next date?  Only you can answer such questions, as it will vary based on your business needs.

The manipulations I described could be done directly in PostgreSQL, using functions like [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) and others, but generally you are better off doing them in your application layer.  Most programming platforms have functions for manipulating dates and times, and for working with time zones.